# Angular 8 memory leak, adds more and more subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

### The problem:

My app is working fine on the first component I load, and when I click to switch to another component, it creates another subscription on My DAL.

### Code

servers.component.html <- the default component

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <app-server-list></app-server-list>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

server-backup.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <app-server-list ></app-server-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

In server-list.component.ts I want to refresh the data from the DB every 5 seconds, so I do this:

```
this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo()
this.interval = setInterval(() =>
{
  this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo()
} , 5000)
```

When I switch between servers and servers-backup I unsubscribe:

```
ngOnDestroy()
{

  this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();  
  });
 clearInterval(this.interval);
```

}

And finally on my data-storage-service.ts

```
getServerPerformanceInfo()
{
  this.serverPerfSub = this.http.get<ServerPerformance[]>(DEV + '/getServerPerformance').subscribe
  (
    (data) => {
      this.serversService.setPerformanceInfo(data);
    }
  )
}
```

As I switch between my components, the server-list component gets destroyed, created, but the dataStorageService calls get more and more frequent until my API method starts failing.

Surely this has to do with the subscribe on the dataStorageService, but how do I clean that?

Comment: I tired without variable. I also tried this: 
if (!this.serverPerfSub)
{
     //get the data
} 
This didn't work.

The problem is when and how to clean the subscription on the DataStorageSerivce? as its always alive and keeps getting more and more calls to my api. The list of subscriptions is not on the dataStorageService

Answer (score 4):

#### Javascript

You need to clear your `setInterval`.

```js
interval: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo()
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo();
  } , 5000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

#### RxJS

This can be done with javascript, but I would recommend using the RxJS `interval` since you are already dealing with observables.

And since you want to immediately invoke it, you would be better off using the RxJS `timer`.

```js
// import { timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
// import { takeUntil, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

private destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  // start the timer and initiate the observable immediately.
  // then emit a value every 5 seconds
  timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    // unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // TODO: catch errors in data storage service
    this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo();
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
  this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```

#### Moving the subscription out of your service

I would recommend moving your subscription out of your service though. You can still perform the action in a `tap` operator. You would use a `switchMap` in your component to chain the service call to your `timer`.

data-storage-service.ts

```js
getServerPerformanceInfo(): Observable<any> {
  const url = DEV + '/getServerPerformance';
  return this.http.get<ServerPerformance[]>(url).pipe(
    tap((data) => this.serversService.setPerformanceInfo(data))    
  );
}
```

component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    switchMap(() => this.dataStorageService.getServerPerformanceInfo()),
    catchError(error => of('An error has occured'))
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // TODO: Something?
  });
}
```

If you want to catch errors, you can catch them in the pipe using `catchError`. I would recommend catching them as close to the source as possible - preferably soon after the http request.

Comment: Thanks, I applied those changes. 

The original error I'm getting ,""The query processor could not start the necessary thread resources for parallel query execution." remains, and now it stops calling the method every 5 seconds after a few calls..

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: I don't have access from my work. However, one thing I do notice that I haven't mentioned is when I log my dataAccessService time, I see it gets called twice every 5 seconds (until it fails and then it just stops trying)

Thu Mar 05 2020 15:13:06 GMT+0200
data-storage.service.ts:100 
Thu Mar 05 2020 15:13:06 GMT+0200 
data-storage.service.ts:100

Comment: Anyways, your code stops on error, and since I still get the same error, it runs until it gets to this error and stops refreshing my data. On the previous method it kept trying. Sometimes succeeding, sometimes failing.

Comment: Ah, if you want error handling, I'll amend my answer

Comment: You didn't mention error handling in your question, but I've added `catchError` to my second example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209091/discussion-between-zion-hai-and-kurt-hamilton).

Comment: I've added a pure javascript version to the start of my answer. Your issue is with the interval continuing to run, not the subscription. By clearing the interval, you don't need to even think about RxJS error handling (although you should).

Comment: I edited my code in the 1st post and added an Interval variable with ClearInterval on the destroy method. The issue remains the same.

Comment: If you can't access stackblitz, then are there any other live demo sites you can access? There's probably something not quite right, but there's no way of knowing without a shared demo.